# Do I need to duplicate my Entity Framework classes in Typescript when using Angular 2?

Tags: entity-framework, angular, typescript

Let's say I have a nice C# backend with Entity Framework. I've got my database set up and a simple class like

```
public class MyItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

I've got a nice Angular2 front end where I retrieve data from an API and present such as...

```
template: '<div>{{ItemName}} - {{ItemID}}</div>'
```

At the moment I have a duplicate, seemingly redundant typescript class ie

```
export class MyItem{
  ItemID: number;
  ItemName: string;
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid this typescript class? Can I bind to an object that isn't defined in advance? In Angular 1 we could bind to any property on the scope
{{MyItem.SomeProperty}}

Comment: When you request a `MyItem` object through the api, how is it passed through? JSON?

Comment: It's redundant, because you can't directly share code between those two language, but it's definitely worth having it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript class/model isn't mandatory.

You can load your HTTP data into a variable and access it like any other object with properties and arrays.  e.g. data.propertyname or data.arrayname[0].propertyname.

In Angular2 you can use the HTTP service and return data which can then be converted into a JSON object using data.json()

Here is an example:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

...

constructor(private http: Http) {
{
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
        data => {
            var json = data.json();
            console.log(json.propertyName);  
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Accepted as the most direct answer to the question showing the ts class isn't needed.

Answer (score 7):

In my project I've used [TypeLite](http://type.litesolutions.net/).
It can generate TypeScript interfaces based on your C# classes. Worked just fine. If you change smth on you backend you'll see errors in your client code without running you app.
If you don't need type safety on the client side, you can use `any` as was said already.

E.g.
Next C# class:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

will be converted to

```
interface Person {
    Name: string;
    Addresses: Address[];
}
```

Also you can use next tools/extensions:

- [TypescriptSyntaxPaste](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NhaBuiDuc.TypescriptSyntaxPaste)
- [TypeWriter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=frhagn.Typewriter) - one more powerfull extension for VS.

Comment: Upvoted for a much better way of creating the typescript class that may make it viable to maintain the ts files

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly get data in an `any` object, However you will loose out on all the Type related feature supported by Typescript.